# Is recurrent neural network a reinforcement learning or supervised learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I just learn Machine learning and some ANN for a while and still need to figure it out the big picture of it.
I'm still learning the basic and terminology to deepen my knowledge.
I have learn about Reinforcement learning and what i understand (please correct me if i wrong) there 3 grouping method learning.

1. unsupervised (example for this is restricted boltzman machine)
2. supervised (CNN)
3. reinforcement (EKF, Particle Filter)

When I learn about recurrent net, some said that it belongs to supervised learning.
But when i see how it works, it more suitable to said that it  belong to reinforcement learning.
can anyone clarify is recurrent net belong to supervised or reinforcement learning?

Comment: Does it use *labeled data*? If yes, it is supervised learning, and not RL (hint: it does).

Comment: The question is legitimate. Not sure why people vote it down. If there is an easy answer to sort a confusion, just give it.

Comment: Voting it up because this does pose a question that needs a through answer. As per my line of thought, it is about nuances of terms vs the terminologies from pre-cloud periods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RNN is always used in supervised learning, because the core functionality of RNN requires labelled data sent in serially.

Now you must have seen RNN in RL too, but the catch is current deep reinforcement learning use the concept of supervised RNN which acts as a good feature vector for agent inside the RL ecosystem.

In simpler terms, the agent, the reward shaping, the environment everything is RL, but the way the deep network in agent learns is using RNN(or CNN or any type of ANN depending upon the problem statement).

So in short RNN always requires labelled data and hence supervised learning, but it can be used in RL environment too.

Answer (score 0):

Supervised learning vs. reinforcement learning. It is almost the same. In supervised learning there is a finite amount of labelled examples. Each example is self standing. All the examples come from the same distribution. If the example is a series of inputs (ex. a sentence made out of words), it is still a single example (ex. "What a lovely day" -> positive).
With RL there are no examples and and at the same time there are infinite number of examples. What??!? Yes, your agent can interact with an environment and this will generate a lot of episodes (ex. "Start -> Left -> 1, 2 -> Up -> 2, 4.."). Or also a sentence (ex. "What -> ah -> a -> go on -> lovely -> not again -> day".). And what is the label? Not clear. Some reward mechanism should be developed to communicate the desired behavior. Also note that the episodes are dependent on the actions the agent takes. So no more "same distribution".